# Variable Function Notation With Absolute Value

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a question on function notation with absolute value.

Here is the function:
$F(x)=|x-1|-|x+1|$.
Find the values $F(-a)$ and $-F(a)$

I know when you solve for $F(-a)$ you get
$F(-a)=|-a-1|-|-a+1|$.
My question is why can I not subtract the two functions why is that the only thing I can do. Can someone show me why I can’t work on this problem further?

For the second I know it looks like this
$-F(a)=-(|a-1|-|a+1|)=-|a+1|+|a+1|$
But why can I not distribute the negative sign inside the absolute value expression? Why can it only be on the outside of each expression?

Are their rules for this particular expression?

Comment: Are you using $F$ and $f$ interchangeably? You mustn't do that. Ah, user @Dominique has decided you were, in fact, using two different symbols for the same thing, and has fixed it for you.

Comment: What do you mean by "subtract the two functions"? Do you mean you want to combine $|r|-|s|$ into $|r-s|$? If so, I encourage you to play with some numerical values for $r$ and $s$ until you figure out why you can't "subtract the two functions".

Comment: As for "distributing the negative sign inside the absolute value sign", I invite you to distribute the negative sign inside $-|2|$, and see what happens.

Comment: Wait for question one about the subtraction is it because when you put in a value like 2 you would get |-3|-|1| which is two different outputs so it’s not correct or is it something else.

Comment: $|-3|-|1|\ne|-3-1|$ since the left side is $2$ and the right side is $4$ (I think this answers your question, though it's hard to tell, since you express yourself so tersely).

Answer (score 0):

"Why can I not distribute the negative sign inside their absolute value expression?" Look at the example $-|5|=-5$ and $|-5|=5$.

You're doing two things here: Multiplying by $-1$ and taking an absolute value. What you're asking is why you can't reverse the order of those two things. But it is usually true that two actions give different results when you reverse their order (if my surgeon gives me anesthesia and then cuts me open, vs. if my surgeon cuts me open and then gives me anesthesia $\ldots$). You shouldn't expect that orders can be reversed until provided with a reason why they can't be; you should expect that they can't be until provided with a reason why they can.

For your first question, you ask why you can't subtract the functions. But you are subtracting the functions. I suspect that you mean to ask is why can't you bring the subtraction inside one set of absolute value symbols, and the answer is the same as the first part. You're doing two things: Subtracting two expressions and taking absolute values. The difference is what you're doing here is taking absolute values first, and then subtracting. You're asking why you can't subtract first and then take the absolute value, and the answer again is that there's no reason why that should lead to the same value, and if it did, that would be a special property that needs proof.

Now what you could do to illustrate this particular example is break things up into cases: For $|-a-1|$ and $|-a+1|$, we have three cases: $-a-1>0$ (which implies $-a+1 >0$ as well), or $-a-1<0<-a+1$, or $-a+1<0$. In the first case, since both expressions are positive, they are equal to their absolute values, and we get $$|-a-1|-|-a+1|=-a-1-(-a+1)=-2. \tag{Case $1$}$$ In case $2$, since $-a-1<0$, $|-a-1|=-(-a-1)=a+1$. In this case, since $-a+1>0$, $|-a+1|=-a+1$, and we get $$|-a-1|-|-a+1|=(a+1)-(-a+1)=2a. \tag{Case 2}.$$ In Case $3$, since both terms are negative, $|-a-1|=-(-a-1)=a+1$ and $|-a+1|=-(-a+1)=a-1$, so $$|-a-1|-|-a+1|=(a+1)-(a-1)=2.\tag{Case $3$}$$ We can see right away that since one of these results is $-2$, it can never be equal to what we get if we take absolute values as the last step.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I think I understand now why I can’t subtract it’s because it’s because they are to different expressions right and then for distributing I can’t do that because it would completely change -f(a) value.  But I did have a question why for case one when you took the absolute value of the function were the signs still negative cause I thought absolute value made any sign positive. I’m just kinda confused on that. Cause I’m probably doing it wrong, but if I were to have subtracted I would have done |-a-1|-||-a+1|=a+1-a+1=0 but why is that wrong.

Comment: Do you mean $$|-a-1|=-a-1?$$ The absolute value makes the **number** inside of it positive. But just because we see minus signs doesn't mean the number in the expression is negative. For example, if $a=-10$, $-a-1=-(-10)-1=+9$. So since $-a-1=+9$ is positive, it is equal to its own absolute value.

Comment: Ohhh so the two expressions are equivalent. So I couldn’t like just change the signs of the -1 in the expression because it would change the entire meaning of the question.

Comment: Right. It's always true that, for example, $|-x|=|x|$. But whether this is equal to $x$ or $-x$ depends on whether $x$ is positive or negative (or, if $x=0$, they're all equal). 

Something we want to be careful of here is that if we're going to use $|-x|=|x|$, we have to change the **entire sign** of the expression inside the absolute value. So $|-a-1|=|a+1|$ (changing all the signs), but I can't say $|-a-1|=|-a+1|$ (changing some but not all of the signs).

Comment: Wait so then is So |−a−1|=|a+1| those two expressions are equivalent. But if those are equivalent then why can’t I just subtract after finding the absolute value of each expression. Also thank you for answering my questions.

Comment: Let's look at an example that's easier to read: $|x|-1$. We're taking the absolute value of $x$ and then subtracting $1$. That's not the same as subtracting $1$ first and then taking the absolute value (which would be $|x-1|$. 

We know $|-x|=|x|$, but we don't know whether this is equal to $x$ or $-x$. 

If $|-x|=|x|=x$, then $|x|-1=x-1$. If $|-x|=|x|=-x$, then $|x|-1=-x-1$, which is not the same as $x-1$.

Without knowing more about $x$, we can't be more specific than $|x|-1$, unless we want to break it out on a case-by-case basis.